# Hive date format

Tags: date, hive

Anybody converted a date from mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format to 
yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format using hive query ?

I have a string with date in the / format need to add some duration in it

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
select 
regexp_replace('2015/04/15','(\\d{4})\\/{1}(\\d{2})\\/{1}(\\d{2})','$1-$2-$3') as dt
from x;
```

**INPUT:2015/04/05**
**OUTPUT:2015-04-05**

Grab four numeric digits (\d{4}), two (\d{2}), and two more (\d{2}) from the original string and put them in that order seperated by dashes.